# Convert string with multiple values into a dict?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe Such as :

```
Path                          Attribute
/home/accessbile/wheelchair   type:threshold;width:42;gaurded:no
/home/accessible/wheelcahir   type:threshold;width:45
/home/accessbile/armchair     weight(lbs):100;width:30
/home/accessible/armchair     type:foldind;weight(lbs):100;width:30
```

I need get the unique count in attributes for values(type ,width ,weight,gaurded , such as..) with respect to path

OUTPUT :

```
    PATH                          Attributes  count


/home/accessbile/wheelchair     type          2
/home/accessbile/wheelchair     width         2
/home/accessbile/wheelchair    gaurded        1
/home/accessbile/armchair      weight(lbs)    2
/home/accessbile/armchair      width          2
/home/accessbile/armchair      type           1
```

tried convert attributes to dict by `ast.eval` and taking key as unique count .. but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check the spellings of all your rows in `Path`, once you fix it, You can do the below:

```
df.Attribute=df.Attribute.str.split(";")
df_new=pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in df.values for z in y],columns=df.columns)
df_new['Attribute']=df_new.Attribute.str.split(":").str[0]
df_new.groupby('Path')['Attribute'].value_counts().reset_index(0).\
               rename(columns={'Attribute':'Count'}).reset_index()

     Attribute                         Path  Count
0         type  /home/accessbile/wheelchair      2
1        width  /home/accessbile/wheelchair      2
2      gaurded  /home/accessbile/wheelchair      1
3  weight(lbs)    /home/accessible/armchair      2
4        width    /home/accessible/armchair      2
5         type    /home/accessible/armchair      1
```